# Where to learn to build a full RDBMS?

Tags: relational-database, implementation

In school, I only learned how to interface with the software that runs the database but not how to build that software. I want to learn how to build the software of a relational database. Is there any resource such as a book, class, webpage, etc. that discusses the architectural features of a relational database and its implementation? I understand that MySQL and Postgres are open source, but I don't have a theoretical understanding, so I feel that examining a repository won't do me much good.

Comment: Not even PhD level are competent to build an (R)DBMS from scratch. They're built and maintained by teams of hundreds or thousands of people, with many different specialities, and taking decades to get to the functionality available in the 'big iron' products. Orders of magnitude greater person-hours than a typical compiler for a HLL. Certainly looking in a repository won't help: that's tens of thousands of lines of low-level code.
Suggest you explain what particular aspects of a DBMS you want to explore. What textbooks are you working from?

Comment: Possible background for the underlying semantics of a DML: https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/APPXA.pdf.  http://www.oreilly.com/data/free/what-is-database-design-anyway.csp

Comment: I want to know about an exact implementation of the B-tree data structure (in C, C++) that is used to store the rows of the database. This can't be some object stored in memory because the size is too large, so it must be stored to the disk. But how is this done in the most efficient way (direct question)?